# How to call a method in java a set number of times

Tags: java, function, for-loop, methods

Could someone give an example of how you would call a method in java x number of times? Something equivalent to

```
for i in range(x):
    function()
```

in python. That would be great, thanks!

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) { function(); }`

Comment: Have you done any research on for loops in Java?

Comment: IntStream stream = IntStream.range(0, x); 
stream.forEach(System.out::println);

Comment: @user888379 Yes, I just wasn't sure if you could use them for methods like you can in python.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash alright I did

Comment: Thanks, @LiamRalph for the confirmation. Wish you success!

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Thanks. You too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as follows in Java:

```
for (int i =1; i <= x; i++) {
    function();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`IntStream.range(0, x).forEach(this::function);`

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on SO. Could you perhaps expand on (for example): why this works, why it is only supported by Java 8 and later, why it is different than other imperative-idiomatic answers, the implications on parallelization, and finally the lack of guarantee on the order of `forEach` calls with respect to the sequence of `Integer`s?

Comment: yes, you should use `forEachOrdered()` method if you want to preserve the order. Although in this case the question was about just repeating number of times, without access to index

Answer (score -2):

```
for (i = 0; i < x; i++){
int x;
// write your code here,in your case:
Function();
}
```

So this function going to call x times.

Comment: There is no `Int` type in Java, there is `int`, and normally you would declare it in the loop-initialization, not before the loop.